# selecting mulitple values using Case statement in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to achieve the followwing in T-SQL, but this syntax in incorrect.
What is the best way to re-write this ?

```
 declare @region varchar(50)

set @region = 'REGION1'

declare cono_cursor CURSOR for
Select CpnyID

     from 
(
Select CASE @region 
    when 'REGION1'  then '116','118','129','131','139','145','906','907','943','948')
    when 'REGION2' then ('113','114','122','130','132','135','136','137','138','941') 
    when 'REGION3' then ('106','107','111','112','123','128','202','916','919') 
 end 
 )A
```

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* - it computes a (single) value. There are probably better ways to approach this problem overall, but you've only shown us a small part of what you're doing - are you sure you even need a `cursor`?

Comment: Yes, I do need a cursor as I have to do multiple calculations for each cpnyid. This is just part of a much larger script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a lookup table with two columns and query that table.